# How to get a string from an xcb_atom_t?

Tags: x11, xrandr, xcb

I want to find out the name of an `xcb_randr_monitor_info_t`. It has a `name` field, but that's of type `xcb_atom_t`, not a `char [255]` or something easy like that. How can I turn it into a (preferably UTF-8) string?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `xcb_get_atom_name_name`

`xcb_get_atom_name_reply_t *reply=xcb_get_atom_name_reply(
       dis, xcb_get_atom_name(dis, atom), NULL);
char*name=xcb_get_atom_name_name(reply);`